# Firebase Realtime Database Android: How to Display Data, Parts at a time

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I needed some help on getting the Firebase Database to display some information from the real-time database.

I am using Firebase Query to display the last 30 items in a list view by using `limitToLast(30)`.

However, I want to display all the data. I know loading too much causes the system to slow down and this is why 30 is optimal.

Is there way to set it up so that when I, scroll down, it hides the top ones from being present, or have some sort of page where when they go to next page, it shows the next 30 posts.

**My Code:**

```
String userID = user.getUid();
        databaseReference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Author author = data.getValue(Author.class);
                    authorList.add(author);
                }
                Layout_Saved_Quotes savedQuotes = new Layout_Saved_Quotes(Show_Saved_Quotes.this, authorList);
                list.setAdapter(savedQuotes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

`Query databaseReference;` 
`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().limitToLast(30);`

Comment: You are looking to implement "pagination", which is arguably best achieved using a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). Using both those terms in your searches should lead you on the right track.

Comment: This [blog post](https://blog.shajeelafzal.com/2017/12/13/firebase-realtime-database-pagination-guide-using-recyclerview/) covers everything you should need. You will just need to change `.startAt(...).limitToFirst(...)` to `.endAt(...).limitToLast(...)` and reverse the array list before adding it to your adapter to keep the items in the right order.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into both suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use a RecyclerView. It will reuse views scrolling through the list.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your query like this. 
`databaseReference.orderByChild("id").startAt(startAt).endAt(startAt + 30)`

You can call it again when `Recyclerview` is scrolled and reached to the end.